# take parameter value of a method into another class's method

Tags: c#

I'm getting an int value from my data table in my method

```
public void GetListing(string url,int ID)
```

i want to access this ID from another method and then assign a update value to it and then save in my table
is it possible to do so?

```
updateMethod(int ID,int Status)
```

Comment: Where / when do you call your `updateMethod`?

Comment: under my GetListing method im calling that method and wanna pass ID to that method but the thing is every time Get listing will get an dynamic/different ID so is this possible to make that ID change in my update method by accessing it through ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the `updateMethod` from the `GetListing()` by passing ID. so the signature of the `GetListing` will be like the following:

```
public void GetListing(string url,int ID)
{
  //Some code here 
  int status=1; // this will be the value of status
  updateMethod(ID, status); // this will call the updateMethod
}
```

And the updateMethod() will be like this;

```
updateMethod(int ID,int Status)
{
 // do something
}
```

Comment: will try it.before that please tell me what is 1 in update method?

Comment: one last thing,will i be able to handle different ID every time? because i am getting every time a different ID in my GetListing method and pass to update method??

Comment: It will use whatever parameter you decide to pass to the `GetListing()` method at that time
Also, recommend renaming `GetListing()` to `getListing()`, methods are generally refered to with lowercase letters at the start

Answer (score -1):

make an object of your class where you have your update method,make the object under your listing class and then you can assign values to that method

Comment: Writing code might explain your point a little better, at this moment it's a little unclear what you mean